# Using external shared library in R

Tags: c++, r, shared-libraries, rcpp

I have written a few c++ function for integration into an R package by Rcpp, and these functions reply on the boost filesystem library. I have specified these in src/Makevar:

```
PKG_LIBS = -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

And the package compiles ok:

==> R CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source txtutils2

```
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -std=c++11 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘txtutils2’ ...
** libs
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -std=c++11 -c bedcollc.cpp -o bedcollc.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -std=c++11 -c bedcollr.cpp -o bedcollr.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -std=c++11 -c countlines.cpp -o countlines.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -std=c++11 -c fileSize.cpp -o fileSize.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -std=c++11 -c ncols.cpp -o ncols.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -std=c++11 -c printlines.cpp -o printlines.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -std=c++11 -c readbed.cpp -o readbed.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -std=c++11 -c readcol.cpp -o readcol.o
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -std=c++11 -c readcols.cpp -o readcols.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -o txtutils2.so RcppExports.o bedcollc.o bedcollr.o countlines.o fileSize.o ncols.o printlines.o readbed.o readcol.o readcols.o -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/txtutils2/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (txtutils2)
```

But when I try to load it, something goes wrong:

```
> library(txtutils2)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/txtutils2/libs/txtutils2.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/txtutils2/libs/txtutils2.so, 6): Library not loaded: libboost_system.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/txtutils2/libs/txtutils2.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘txtutils2’
```

I am on osx 10.10, if that matters.

General instructions on usage of external shared libs in R is also most welcome.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether your problem is a) linking against a Boost library (which we just answered this week), or b) linking against a set of your files (which should work by default), or c) something else I not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, what you have met is not the problem of Rcpp even not the problem of R. It may be about linking on OSX.

I don't use Mac, so I just give you some advice. Try

```
otool -L yourpackagename.so
```

You should see a link to the boost library you use. You need to check whether the path is right.